# webclient downloadstring(URI), URI has 10 mb file. Can I download a certain size of this file?

Tags: c#, webclient

I have a 10 mb file at an URI 
I download it with the following codes.

WebClient wc = new WebClient();
string file = wc.DownloadString(http://www......com);

Can I download certain sizes of this file, such as 1 mb, 5 mb. not whole 10 mb. ?
Then stop downloading?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add the HTTP Range header in your request. Note that this will only work if the server supports it.

See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html for more information about it

Answer (score 0):

you can use httpwebrequest to getresponse. load whatever lines you want. check:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

the example use ReadToEnd. you can use other methods to read just part of it.